# How to Filter Very High Voltage Power Supply Noise

Tags: power-supply, rf, filter

Any suggestions of how to filter out this noise? Basic filter math is not working out.

I am adapting a cheap commercial HV supply (variable DC voltage up to 40kV at 10mA) for physics experiments.  The supply works adequately, but it has output noise I can’t seem to filter away.

The noise comes as regular high frequency pings at a significant percentage of total voltage.  For example (at 20kV into a 4 MOhm load), there is a ping each 18us with a maximum amplitude both up and down 6kv from the base 20kV.  The frequency of the ping is about 36 MHz and it mostly fades away after 500ns.
An RC filter (10k Ohm / 4nF) cuts this noise in half, but the results are far short of theory, and this still leaves a big spike.   The capacitors are high voltage polyester & foil caps.  LTSpice modeling with ideal components suggests that I should have a clean output, so I assume that real capacitors, resistors & wires are not ideal at this high frequency and high voltage.

Adding ferrite rings between the R and C cut it about 10% more.

Another thought I have not yet tried is to loop the HV wire a few times around a ferrite torroid and then add a separate single short-circuit loop to act as a short circuited transformer secondary. My thinking is that this would pass the DC but waste the AC part into heat.

Comment: Did you check the series resonant frequency of your 4 uF capacitor before using it in the filter?

Comment: If I understand correctly, my problem could be that above some frequency, the capacitor becomes more inductive than capacitive?  I don't have specs on the capacitor series resonance, but they are physically large (two 2uF caps each as 1 inch cylinders).  I guess that I could test the RC circuit with a low voltage frequency generator to measure capacitance at high frequency..  right?

Comment: Use smaller caps

Comment: The problem with high voltage is that the caps are always physically big.  At this high frequency (36MHz) perhaps it is better to go for inductive filtering?

Comment: Correction...  The caps are 2 x 2nF  (not uF as I wrote in the original question).

Comment: How are you measuring this ping?

Comment: I'm measuring the ping on an oscilloscope through a home made 10,000/1 voltage divider.

Comment: Hi Photon - I think your hint is correct.  I tried a 100nF ceramic capacitor and get somewhat better regulation than with the big 4nF film cap. (+/-2kV vs +/- 3kV).   Still a long way from smooth output though

Comment: Did you model the parasitics of your system?

Comment: I've modeled it adding serial resistance and inductance to match some experimental results, but it takes about 20uH of inductance which seems unbelievable to me.

Comment: I tested the capacitors up to 2MHz (the highest frequeny my signal generator has) and they still act more like capacitors than inductors.

Comment: My latest guess is that the entire test set-up is acting like a giant antenna giving me false readings on the O-Scope.  My 4MOhm load resistor is actually 56 resistors in a 14x4 array in a plastic tray.  My RC filter is similarly open with long lead spacing to prevent arcs.     Nest weekend, I'll try this again but with short leads and imbed it in oil to prevent arcing.  Also, I'll try shielding the PSU case which is just plastic.

Comment: Yes I support your last ideas. Most likely, the switching noise you see is not real.

Comment: You can measure enormous voltages like that quite easily by holding a probe "near" the live parts. Caveat, 40kV will destroy your oscilloscope without trying if you actually touch a conductive part with it. In fact I hope you're being damn careful with that thing, 4nF charged to 40kV is nothing to sneeze at. IEC62368 considers capacitance over 0.2nF at 40kV dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that there is noise being coupled in from whatever is driving the system, I'm going to assume this is either a HV flyback or a voltage multiplier (and from the some od it, the multiplier seems mpre likely). Now when the switcher in the base turns on, it dumps all it's energy onto the stack in short sharp bursts (you get the same problems when rectifying AC feeding a big smoo5hing capacitor). Now at 10k ohms, your filter will allow A LOT of current to flow into your smoothing capacitor. Try either adding an extra cap directly to the output *before* the filter and/or increase the value of the resistor substantially (try 100k) and if that's still not enough, try (as Eric suggested) adding some large inductors to the output (start with something in the millihenry range) and see what happens.